# Where can i find IHttpClientBuilder in a console app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

- Visual Studio 2022.
- .Net 6 Console app

I have a Web Application which i am now converting to a console app using `HttpClient`.

I noticed in the Web app i saw the builder from `WebApplicationBuilder`.

Ive added a few packages including

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
```

In `Program.cs` i add

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

host.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHttpClient(); 
});
```

but i cant find `IHttpClientBuilder` which contains the extension method i would like access to (i can provide the extension method if anyone likes but if this puzzle could be resolved i think i would know what to do)?

I have tried different methods instead of `CreateDefaultBuilder` but i cant seem to find any relation to `IHttpClientBuilder`.

Am i missing another package or do i need to reconfigure the code above?

Comment: This interface was include in `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` namespace. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/